# Bulk upload of large files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

Hii all,
        I would like to upload some large size(>6gb) in bulk  in rails , running mongrel as my server .i am able to upload large file of size 7gb but i am doing it one file upload at a time  ..,i am looking for a situation where all large file i put in a folder and upload that folder say folder size is 20gb ...
Could  anyone tell me how can achieve this in rails???

Comment: what are your specs? should it be a cron job? how much memory does your machine(uploader) have?

Comment: i have 80 gb of hard drive with 2gb of RAM,am doing it through ruby code but i would like to upload large files in bulk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/04/10/rails-and-large-large-file-uploads-looking-at-the-alternatives/) has some good comparisons of the options, including some outside of Rails.

Comment: SWFUpload allows multiple uploads in Rails: http://blog.alastairdawson.com/2006/09/08/multiple-file-upload-with-flash-and-ruby-on-rails/ but I think that would limit your options somewhat. Maybe you could do something with FTP as per this Stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710080/rails-upload-file-to-ftp-server

Comment: That site is for Rails 2. I'm not sure that it's so useful.