# How to FTP in Ruby without first saving the text file

Tags: ruby, ftp, heroku

Since Heroku does not allow saving dynamic files to disk, I've run into a dilemma that I am hoping you can help me overcome. I have a text file that I can create in RAM. The problem is that I cannot find a gem or function that would allow me to stream the file to another FTP server. The Net/FTP gem I am using requires that I save the file to disk first. Any suggestions?

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new(domain)
ftp.passive = true
ftp.login(username, password)
ftp.chdir(path_on_server)
ftp.puttextfile(path_to_web_file)
ftp.close
```

The ftp.puttextfile function is what is requiring a physical file to exist.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[StringIO.new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/classes/StringIO.html#M003790) provides an object that acts like an opened file. It's easy to create a method like [puttextfile](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/classes/Net/FTP.html#M001277), by using StringIO object instead of file.

```
require 'net/ftp'
require 'stringio'

class Net::FTP
  def puttextcontent(content, remotefile, &block)
    f = StringIO.new(content)
    begin
      storlines("STOR " + remotefile, f, &block)
    ensure
      f.close
    end
  end
end

file_content = <<filecontent
<html>
  <head><title>Hello!</title></head>
  <body>Hello.</body>
</html>
filecontent

ftp = Net::FTP.new(domain)
ftp.passive = true
ftp.login(username, password)
ftp.chdir(path_on_server)
ftp.puttextcontent(file_content, path_to_web_file)
ftp.close
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Helped me upload a file from a Rails app. Any idea on where to expect errors?

Answer (score 5):

David at Heroku gave a prompt response to a support ticket I entered there.

> You can use APP_ROOT/tmp for temporary file output. The existence of files created in this dir is not guaranteed outside the life of a single request, but it should work for your purposes.
>
> Hope this helps,
> David

Comment: Thank you for the response, David. Keep up the great work at Heroku!

Comment: Ruby offer 'Tempfile' : https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html