# Loading data from an FTP to Heroku App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, ftp

a little background first. I've been working on an inventory app for my company, and part of the program pulls in orders from various sites where my company sells product (amazon, website, etc). We've started using Buy.com, and the only way they currently store order history is via an FTP. I've gotten this working locally, but when I load it to heroku, it errors (BrokenPipe)

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new('example.com')
ftp.login(user = "username", passwd = "pass")
files = ftp.chdir('/Orders')
files = ftp.list('*.txt')
(0..(files.count-1)).to_a.each do |i|
    ftp.getbinaryfile(files[i].split(' ').last, 'order.txt', 1024)
    # use order.txt to load data to db
end
```

the problem is that it starts erroring at the list command. Any help would be greatly appreciated. and let me know if I left out any info!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try it on the command line? You can run `heroku console` and go through each command to see what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, I did, which is how I got the BrokenPipe Error...

Comment: This other SO question has the answers I was just thinking of.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223763/how-to-ftp-in-ruby-without-first-saving-the-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is a read only file system. So doing that directly is not possible. I suggest trying to transfer to information to S3, where you can pull that information from Heroku using gems like `fog`.

Comment: well there's nothing that says I _need_ to save the file. any idea if there is a way to directly read the text file from the ftp?

Comment: Also, its erroring on the list command, which isnt writing anything to heroku

Comment: Because there's no pure ruby implementation of `ftp` as far as I know, my guess would be Heroku would explicitly disallow this. Similarly, programs like curl would not work from within Heroku either.