# POST file directly from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rest, post, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have a string:
`text = "a bc def"` and need to send it to a REST API call which uses 'multipart' to take a POST call with a file. Looks something like this:

```
post '/upload' do
  tempfile = params[:file][:tempfile] 
  filename = params[:file][:filename] 
  cp(tempfile.path, "public/uploads/#{filename}")
end
```

I can write the `text` string to a temp file locally under `/tmp/some/temp/folder/abc.txt` and send it by making a POST call, but is there a way to directly send it without writing it to local file system? That way I believe would be more efficient. Do I need to encode it first? Would Base64 encode work?

```
require "base64"
encoded_file = Base64.encode64(text)
send_by_post(encoded_file)
```

I can only use Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Did you tried that code?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to work though. Any other ways?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223763/how-to-ftp-in-ruby-without-first-saving-the-text-file