# How do I copy a file onto a separate server using Net::FTP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp, net-ftp

I'm building a Rails app which creates a bookmarklet file for each user upon sign-up. I'd like to save that file onto a remote server, so I'm trying Ruby's Net::FTP, based on ["Rails upload file to ftp server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710080/rails-upload-file-to-ftp-server).

I tried this code:

```
  require 'net/ftp'

  FileUtils.cp('public/ext/files/script.js', 'public/ext/bookmarklets/'+resource.authentication_token )
  file = File.open('public/ext/bookmarklets/'+resource.authentication_token, 'a') {|f| f.puts("cb_bookmarklet.init('"+resource.username+"', '"+resource.authentication_token+"', '"+resource.id.to_s+"');$('<link>', {href: '//***.com/bookmarklet/cb.css',rel: 'stylesheet',type: 'text/css'}).appendTo('head');});"); return f }
  ftp = Net::FTP.new('www.***.com')
  ftp.passive = true
  ftp.login(user = '***', psswd = '***')
  ftp.storbinary("STOR " + file.original_filename, StringIO.new(file.read), Net::FTP::DEFAULT_BLOCKSIZE)
  ftp.quit()
```

But I'm getting an error that the file variable is nil. I may be doing several things wrong here. I'm pretty new to Ruby and Rails, so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block form of `File.open` does not return the file handle (and even if it did, it would be closed at that point). Perhaps change your code to roughly:

```
require '…'
FileUtils.cp …
File.open('…','a') do |file|
  ftp = …
  ftp.storbinary("STOR #{file.original_filename}", StringIO.new(file.read))
  ftp.quit
end
```

Alternatively:

```
require '…'
FileUtils.cp …
filename = '…'
contents = IO.read(filename)
ftp = …
ftp.storbinary("STOR #{filename}", StringIO.new(contents))
ftp.quit
```

Comment: @BonChampion Note that what you probably really want is: `File.open('…','a'){ |file| … ftp.storbinary("STOR …", file) … }`; specifically, are you certain that a `StringIO` object is needed at all?